# Getting issue with single quotation

Tags: javascript, lightning

the below used to create org chart . but i want to pass a dynamic parameter in onclick event in hyperlink
But getting issue with single quotation

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" standardcontroller="IAP__c" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" extensions="OrganizationalElementOrgChartCTR" >

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {packages:["orgchart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
        data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

        // For each orgchart box, provide the name, manager, and tooltip to show.
        data.addRows([
         <apex:repeat value="{!wrapEleList}" var="orgVar">

          [{v:'{!orgVar.orgEle.id}', f:'<a href="#" onclick=callFun('{!orgVar.orgEle.id}');>{!orgVar.orgEle.name}</a><div style="color:black; font-style:italic">{!orgVar.orgEle.Leader__r.name__c}</div>'},
           '{!orgVar.parentId}', 'The President'],

          </apex:repeat>
        ]);

        // Create the chart.
        var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        // Draw the chart, setting the allowHtml option to true for the tooltips.
        chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true});
      }

      function callFun(org){
        alert(org)
      }
   </script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>


</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi Sarath, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to read [ask], scroll through the [tour], and visit the [help]. **Please share what the issue actually is.**

Answer (score 2):

Remember that every time you use a field that is going to go to a Javascript and is likely to have characters that might break your JS, you should use `JSENCODE`

like ...

```
[
    {
        v:'{!orgVar.orgEle.id}', 
        f:'<a href="#" onclick="callFun(\''{!orgVar.orgEle.id}'\');">{!JSENCODE(orgVar.orgEle.name)}</a><div style="color:black; font-style:italic">{!JSENCODE(orgVar.orgEle.Leader__r.name__c)}</div>'
    },'{!orgVar.parentId}', 
    'The President'
],
```

So salesforce escapes the required characters

Its also helpful the `JSINHTMLENCODE` in case you are using it for securing display inside HTML, etc.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm

Have a look at [Why are there 3 functions to encode in Visualforce?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155285/why-are-there-3-functions-to-encode-in-visualforce/155295) to see more details